# How to run Master Server from Equinox OSGi console?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, equinox, scada

I just configured a Master Server with **Eclipse SCADA** (as application profile project) following this tutorial (referred to the "old" openSCADA): 
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseSCADA/Tutorials/EclipseMagazin .
After generating the output files from the .esim infrastructure file, I would run the **master node** (master.profile.xml) externally from Eclipse, just by using the Equinox OSGi console, instead of right clicking on it and use *"Run as -> Run Equinox Application Profile"* inside Eclipse.
There is a way?

Something says me that it is possible. I started a RCP Application under Equinox by using the OSGi console, just setting up the configuration file, installing the exported application bundle and then running it. I am convinced that a similar procedure is applicable for the master server execution.
Every kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks for your attention.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It is necessary to run the launch configuration file of the system node (master node). It can be launched directly by using a command line.